# Amazon S3 bucket objects access

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am uploading user videos on S3 bucket, i want to make restricted access to these videos. My application hosted on three locations.

1) Web application on a server.
2) I Phone app
3) Android app

After uploading the video on S3 bucket i store the URL(Cloud front web URL) in DB. All the above app query the db and pass the URL to players.

Currently the videos are public, how i can restrict these videos to only access by the 3 apps mentioned above.

I have tried IP restriction, HTTP referrer, authenticated access. The last option look like work, but anyone who has the authenticated URL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're serving content via Amazon S3 and Amazon CloudFront, the best way to serve private content would be:

1. Secure the content in **S3** so that it can only be accessed via CloudFront
2. Secure the content in **CloudFront** so that it can only be accessed via Signed URLs
3. Have your application generate **Signed URLs** so that authorized users can access the content from CloudFront

A **Signed URL** is a way to permit access to private content for a limited time. For details, see: [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, if i do signed url and if someone gets the signed url from the page source. He can view the video? am i right?

Comment: Yes, the signed URL will work for anyone, but only for a limited time (eg 5 minutes) that you specify when signing the request. Every time the page is generated, it will generate a new Signed URL valid for a specific period of time.